# AVMIDIPlayer DLSBankManager::AddBank: Bank load failed

Tags: midi, swift3, ios10

When I use AVMIDIPlayer to play a MusicSequence with only one note message. Most of times it works fine but sometimes it has no sound and logged as below:

```
DLSBankManager::AddBank: Bank load failed
Error Domain=com.apple.coreaudio.avfaudio Code=-10871 "(null)"
```

It works well on iOS9, but when i test it on iOS10 it runs into this issue.
I'm sure that the sf2 sound bank file url is set properly.
I paste the code as below:

```
func playAVMIDIPlayerPreview(_ musicSequence:MusicSequence) {

    guard let bankURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "FluidR3 GM2-2", withExtension: "sf2") else {
        fatalError("soundbank file not found.")
    }

    var status = OSStatus(noErr)
    var data:Unmanaged<CFData>?
    status = MusicSequenceFileCreateData (musicSequence,
                                          MusicSequenceFileTypeID.midiType,
                                          MusicSequenceFileFlags.eraseFile,
                                          480, &data)

    if status != OSStatus(noErr) {
        print("bad status \(status)")
    }

    if let md = data {
        let midiData = md.takeUnretainedValue() as Data
        do {
            try self.midiPlayerPreview = AVMIDIPlayer(data: midiData, soundBankURL: bankURL)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Error \(error)")
        }
        data?.release()

        self.midiPlayerPreview?.play({ () -> Void in
            self.midiPlayerPreview = nil
            self.musicSequencePreview = nil
        })
    }

}
```

The error is occur on this line:

```
try self.midiPlayerPreview = AVMIDIPlayer(data: midiData, soundBankURL: bankURL)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the global variable errno to 0 `errno = 0` before loading the soundfont with

```
try self.midiPlayerPreview = AVMIDIPlayer(data: midiData, soundBankURL: bankURL)
```

We experienced the same issue and at the same time [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39437155/musicsequencefileload-returns-1-on-ios10-audiotoolbox-musicplayer).
So we tried to apply the fix of the other issue to this one and it just worked.

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply. But could tell me where to set the 'errno' in my code?

Comment: Great, it works well now. Thanks very much for your help

Comment: What is this 'errno' variable?

Comment: errno is a C variable used to store error numbers sequentially : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Errno.h